# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a mi pagina web sin el index.html?

Tags: javascript

Hay páginas que no tienen index.html, como "youtube.com/". Entonces me pregunto como funciona si no lleva "youtube.com/index.html". Quisiera hacer lo mismo con mi página web.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo unico que debes poner es tu propia ruta absoluta.
Ejemplo:
**https://miweb.com/**

El navegador interpreta que al entrar a esa URL cargará el index por defecto.

Comment: De la misma forma, el servidor tiene configuraciones que le permiten servir por defecto un recurso dado cuando le piden la raíz del sitio, etc.